# Access the whole item in ng-options in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

Not sure how else to title this. I'm using ng-options to generate a drop down. The source array is of the following form:

```
[{
    id:1,
    name: 'Bob'
 },
 {
    id:2,
    name: 'Tom'
 }...(etc)
]
```

my ng-options looks like this:

```
ng-options="item.name as item.name for item in myObj
```

which I need since the `ng-model` is to the `name` elsewhere. However, on the `ng-change`, I want to send (among other things) the `item.id`. But I can't figure out how to access that at that point.  Not only is `item.id` undefined in the `ng-change`, even `item` is undefined at that point. But, I can't use it in the `ng-options since I need it to model to the name elsewhere.

How do I access `item.id` for use in the `ng-change`?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
item as item.name
```

Comment: Thanks. That actually didn't work since I needed the model to be just the name. In the end, I figured out how to send the data a different way, but thank you!